# does \' and \x27 in Javascript has any difference?

Tags: javascript, encoding, owasp, encoder

I am reading the doc of [owasp-java-encoder](https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html), it says that `forJavaScriptBlock`  performs  the same encode as `forJavaScript` with the exception that " and ' are encoded as \" and \' respectively. I don't understand why ' is encoded as \x27 in `forJavaScript` but endocded as \' in `forJavaScriptBlock`. What is the difference between \' and \x27?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`forJavaScript` says](https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html#forJavaScript-java.lang.String-):

> Encodes for a JavaScript string. It is safe for use in **HTML script attributes (such as onclick)**, script blocks, JSON files, and JavaScript source.

Since an HTML attribute can be delimited with `'` characters, the content cannot include any `'` characters. They have to be represented a different way.

`forJavaScriptSource`, on the other hand, says:

> This method encodes for JavaScript strings contained within HTML
>   script blocks. **It is NOT safe for use in script attributes (such as
>   onclick)**. The caller must provide the surrounding quotation
>   characters. This method performs the same encode as
>   forJavaScript(String) with the exception that `"` and `'` are encoded as
>   `\"` and `\'` respectively.
>
> Unless you are interested in saving a few bytes of output or are
>   writing a framework on top of this library, it is recommend that you
>   use forJavaScript(String) over this method.

Comment: Got it.i did't realize that `<a href=# onclick="alert(\"x\")">ClickMe</a>` would not give us a popup window before you give this answer.Thank you very much.